# C++ array of 192 bitsets to 4 24char array

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit, bit-shift, bitset

I want to convert between the following to formats:

```cpp
#include <bitset>

std::bitset<4> input[192]; // (4 * 192 bits = 768 bits)

char output[4][24];        // (4 * 24 bytes = 768 bits)
```

Specifically, I would like to convert each of the four bits, in the `bitset`s, as separated `char[24]` arrays.

How would do that the easiest and the fastest way?

Comment: what is `Bitsets` ? did you mean `bitset`?

Comment: Yes :) I mean bitset

Comment: `char[24]` did you mean `char[4]`?

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output

Comment: It's not clear how you go from 4*192 = 768 bits to 8*24 = 192 bits. It doesn't fit. Maybe you mean something by 'separated' but if so it's not clear to me what that is.

Comment: Maybe [`to_string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/to_string/) work?

Comment: to avoid bit manipulation operators you may loop through bitset array 
```for (size_t j = 0; j < 192; ++j) {
unsigned long i = arr[j].to_ulong(); 
unsigned char c = static_cast<unsigned char>( i );```

Comment: So I guess you are talking about all the bits at index 0 from the bitsets into one char[24] array, and all the bits at index 1 into another char[24] array etc. Is that right? If so then I don't think there's a way that is easier or faster than the obvious loops.

Comment: @john, that is exactly what I mean. But I have a little trouble making it work, I'm a noob :) could you provide me with an example in how to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply use a nested for loop:

```
constexpr int kSize1 = 4;
constexpr int kSize2 = 24;
constexpr int kBitsPerChar = 8;

void convert(std::array<std::bitset<kSize1>, kSize2 *  kBitsPerChar> &input,
             std::array<std::array<char, kSize2>, kSize1> &output)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < kSize1; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < kSize2; ++j)
        {
            char &c = output[i][j];
            c = 0;
            for (int bit = 0; bit < kBitsPerChar; ++bit)
            {
                c |= input[j * kBitsPerChar + bit][i] << bit;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I did to make it reasonably safe is defining constants for all dimensions, which I use in both the array declarations and the for loop. You should choose more meaningful names than `kSize1`, depending on your context.

The line that actually "does the work" is quite straight forward: I fetch one bit from the source array, shift it to the correct position within the current char and update the destination array.